# Grouping XML attributes in a nested object

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, jackson, pojo

I would like to group certain XML attributes into a nested object. Given XML that looks like this:

```
  <root a="1" b="2" x="3" y="4" />
```

I want to map the data to POJOs that are structured like this:

```
class Root {
   public GroupA groupa;
   public GroupX groupx;  
}

class GroupA {
   public String a;
   public String b;
}

class GroupX {
   public String x;
   public String y;
}
```

Is that something that is possible using jackson-databind-xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `@JsonUnwrapped` for `groupa` and `groupx` would allow flattening of those. And then possibly use of annotation for denoting serialize-as-attribute (`@JacksonXmlProperty(attribute=true)` or something) on properties could do it.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. I should have read more than just the xml annotation docs ;)